# How to get the symbol of plus as it is from $_REQUEST - regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, request

How to pass the symbol of plus `+` as it is when you want to pass it into $_REQUEST?

For instance, I want to pass this,

```
xxx.php?key=xPo8lUEXpqg8bKL+32o6yIOK
```

and I want to get `xPo8lUEXpqg8bKL+32o6yIOK` in echo $_REQUEST['key']; but I will get this below instead -

```
xPo8lUEXpqg8bKL 32o6yIOK
```

What should I do to fix this? Regular expressions again??

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `%2B` instead of `+`, as `+` is the URL-encoded symbol for a space. In general, you should use [`urlencode()`](http://us.php.net/urlencode) to escape things properly:

```
$url = "xxx.php?key=" . urlencode('xPo8lUEXpqg8bKL+32o6yIOK');
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a reserved character in a URL and decodes to a space.

Do a `urlencode()` on the string before attaching it to the URL.